# Show that at least 3 pairwise differences are equal from the set $\{1, 2, ..., 90\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, 90\}$. From $S$, $19$ distinct integers are chosen. Show that among all the different possible pairwise differences of these $19$ integers (all are positive), at least $3$ are equal.

My approach was to first consider how many pair-wise differences there are. It is easy to show that this total is equal to: $18 + 17 + 16 + 15 + \dots + 1$ = $\frac{18(18+1)}{2} = 171$. This means that the set of possible differences, $S_{d}$, contains $171$ integers in the range $[1, 89]$. From here, I am not really sure if my method works. I tried considering rearranging $S_d$ by subtracting the smallest element from every other, which would create a new "difference set" with $170$ integers in the range $[1, 88]$. This could then be done similarly several times, until one gets down to a set with $123$ integers in the range $[1, 41]$. Since $123 = 41\cdot 3$, This would imply that there is at least one triplett of integers in the set, which would mean that (since a constant number - the least in the existing "difference set" - is always subtracted from the rest in each step) there exists at least one triplett of integers in the original set, $S_d$.

As I said, I am not sure at all if this method works, and any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you meant to write $S = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 90\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the $19$ integers are $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{19}$, listed in ascending order, so
$$1 \le x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_{19} \le 90$$
For the sake of brevity, define positive integers $a_i = x_{i+1} - x_i$ for $1 \le i \le 18$, and let $T$ be the sum of the $a_i$'s, so
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^{18} a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{18} (x_{i+1} - x_i) = x_{19} - x_1 \le 90 -1 = 89$$
(The sum telescopes.)

We claim at least three of the $a_i$'s are equal.  Suppose not, so each $a_i$ appears with multiplicity at most two; then there are at most two $1$'s, at most two $2$'s, etc. among the list of $a_i$'s. We can use this assumption to compute a lower bound on $T$:
$$T \ge \underbrace{1+1+2+2+ \dots +9+9}_\text{18 numbers} = 90$$
contradicting $T \le 89$.  This shows our assumption that each $a_i$ occurs at most twice must be false; some value must appear at least three times.

Answer (score 0):

Note $a_i$, $i=1 ...19$ our set of integers, with $a_i < a_{i+1}$

And we consider that we don't have 3 couples $(a_i,a_j)$ with same difference.

Let $d_1 = \Sigma (a_{i+1}-a_i)$ ; $d_1$ is the sum of $18$ integers, and $d_1=a_{19}-a_1 \le 98$

Let $d_2 = \Sigma (a_{i+2}-a_i)$ ; $d_2$ is the sum of $17$ integers, and $d_2=(a_{19}-a_1)+(a_{18}-a_2)$ ; so $d_2 \le 98+96$

Let $d_3 = \Sigma (a_{i+3}-a_i)$ ; $d_3$ is the sum of $16$ integers, and $d_2=(a_{19}-a_1)+(a_{18}-a_2)+(a_{17}-a_3)$ ; so $d_3 \le 98+96+92$

Continue until $d_9$

Let $d_9 = \Sigma (a_{i+9}-a_i)$ ; $d_9$ is the sum of $10$ integers, and $d_9=(a_{19}-a_1)+(a_{18}-a_2)+(a_{17}-a_3)+(a_{16}-a_4)+(a_{15}-a_5)+(a_{14}-a_6)+(a_{13}-a_7)+(a_{12}-a_8)+(a_{11}-a_9)$

So $d_9 \le 98+96+92+86+78+68+56+42+26$

$d_1+d_2+...+d_9$ is the sum of 126 integers, it is less or egal than $(98)+(98+96)+(98+96+92)...=3750$, and this set of $126$ integers doesn't contain 3 integers with same value.

The minimum sum of $126$ integers, without triplicate is $(1+2+...+63) \times 2$.

This number is $63\times 64=4032$, it is greater than $3750$.

So we cannot find a set of integers which respects all constraints.

Comment: All your $98$'s should be $89$'s, as far as I can see. So your argument doesn't work.

Comment: I think that original question was with 99 instead of 90. BTW, if it is not possible to have 19 integers in {1...99} with the constraints given by OP, it is also not possible when we limit the interval to [1,90].

Comment: Yes, I see -- the original question had $90$ in the title, but $99$ in the text.